# E2E testing with serverside template preprocessing -- possible?

Tags: testing, angularjs

I've been playing around with Angular the past week or so learning its ins and outs. I am now at a point where I'm trying to figure out the best way to restructure my app to do E2E testing, given that it will be embedded into a preexisting site, rather than stand on its own.

The problem comes in how to handle `index.html` from the angular-seed project, since my understanding is that `Karma` needs to point itself via `scenarios.js` at something in order to load and bootstrap the app before testing.

The markup currently in `index.html` will need to be inserted into the larger HTML structure of my page when it is being put together by our servers. There is no further preprocessing that must be done to the top-level Angular template, but this seems to be enough to complicate the testing process considerably.

This leaves me with three options as far as I can tell for enabling E2E testing:

1) duplicate the `index.html` code in its entirety to keep around as a complete mockup for testing

2) use a single angular route and `ngView` to access my top level view template (reducing the test purposes `index.html` to little more than `<ng-view></ng-view>` and `<script>` tags)

3) fold and just use Selenium for high-level testing

The first option introduces a maintainability problem, and the second is undesirable because it limits the testability of any aspect of the app outside the `<ng-view>`. Not an issue now, but could be as the app grows. And three, well, I've heard Selenium creates a lot of headaches with Angular apps that are best avoided by using the purpose-built Angular E2E testing tools.

So how is this situation typically handled?